# How do you retrieve the amount of free physical RAM in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, unix, memory

I am specifically talking about physical RAM, I do not want virtual memory stats to be included. I am on Mac OSX Snow leopard but would prefer a solution that would work on ALL OS X platforms (i.e. Lion). I am using Objective-C but solutions in C would also obviously be valid.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need this information?

Comment: @bneely My program monitors different aspects of the computer, and it requires the total amount of free physical RAM as part of system information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to be able to report is the same stuff that the command line utility vm_stat displays? If so then it's probably easiest just to [check out its source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-541/vm_stat.tproj/vm_stat.c), which is amongst the stuff Apple provide as open source.

The relevant code is at the bottom; it all falls back on a call to `host_statistics64`, which appears to be defined via `mach/mach.h`. A quick search of my machine shows it also to be available (or, at least, defined) in iOS.

Comment: vm_stat provides virtual memory stats, but I need the amount of free physical memory only.

Comment: "Free physical memory" is kind of a meaningless term.  Why do you need it?

Comment: Based on e.g. http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/gnumach-doc/ that's probably all Mach reports. It's also exactly the figures returned by both the Activity Monitor and iStat Pro.

Comment: @Farhad Raging Menace has done this for you with [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/). The code is GPL, so you can look at it and see that they are using `host_statistics` and that the free space is calculated from `vm_statistics` as `(free_count + inactive_count) * vm_page_size`

Comment: @HotLicks Physical memory is superior to virtual memory. I need physical memory stats much like the info provided in Activity Monitor because I am trying to inform the user of how much percent of the RAM they are using, and physical memory seems more appropriate. Isn't physical RAM a true representation of memory since VM is just hard drive storage that simulates memory?

Comment: @Farhad no, the virtual memory subsystem is what manages the difference between the per-app logical memory layout and the physical. So, for example, it allows fragmented free spaces in physical memory to appear to be a contiguous block to client applications, and it ensures that all applications have their own (hopefully sealed) memory space. Some virtual memory systems make use of a page file but it's an orthogonal issue — iOS has a fully functioning virtual memory system but no page file for example.

Comment: @Tommy Thanks, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Tommy Sorry, just one more thing. In activity monitor, it provides the amount of memory free, wired, active, inactive and used. Those are VM Memory Stats right?

Comment: @Farhad -- In a paging VM system there is never really a quantity one would call "free physical memory".  In general, pages are "stolen" as needed, so until a page is needed it's occupied by the prior contents that may or may not be valid.  At best you can attempt to measure the number of pages that are "steal candidates", but that would be a poor measure.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks. In System Monitor though a variety of exact memory stats are provided (free, wired etc.). Are these virtual memory stats then since physical memory can't be measured? Because they add up to the total amount of physical memory I have.

Comment: @Farhad I'm definitely under the impression that the host_statistics stats are what the Activity Monitor is displaying but I'm not able to find an authoritative reference either way.

Comment: @Tommy I'll take your word. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to return the amount of physical RAM of the system in bytes as an `unsigned long long` integer:

```
-(unsigned long long)getPhysicalMemoryValue{
    NSProcessInfo *pinfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
    return [pinfo physicalMemory];
}
```

Comment: could you please help me to figure out how much ram the OSX is using via objective c @Brandon B